# Finding the intersection of two arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

This was an Amazon interview question I had an my answer was

```
function intersection ( A , B ) 
{
    var C = [];
    for ( var a in A ) if ( B.indexOf(a) != -1 ) C.push(a);
    return C;
}
```

and he asked what the order of complexity was and I said, and I quote exactly,

> O(m * n) where m=A.length and n=B.length

and he was saying there's a better way to do it and I was like WTF??????? He was saying use `A` and `B` as Objects and I was like

> "But you said these were **arrays** That was your question!!!!"

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: I'm not sure how 'use as objects' helps, but if you make a lookup-table (dictionary) from `B` before you start, then you can do it in O(n).

Comment: If you're in another JavaScript interview, don't use `for ... in` to loop through arrays.

Comment: btw there are lots of questions on SO for this question, eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript

Comment: Creating a looking up table from B would require touching each element of B plus the complexity of inserting into the dictionary.  The complexity would remain O(m * n)

Comment: @JonTrauntvein no it would be O(n+m) which is really just O(n)

Comment: If `A` and `B` are arrays, this won't do what it pretends to. In `for (var a in A) { ... }` the variable `a` will hold the indices.

Answer (score 6):

If you know that the array values are strings or numbers, you can create an object that's got the values as property names and truthy values for each. Then you can use simple object lookup in a pass through the second array.

Something like:

```
function intersection ( A , B ) 
{
    var m = A.reduce(function(m, v) { m[v] = 1; return m; }, {});
    return B.filter(function(v) { return m[v]; });
}
```

*edit* — to remove duplicates from the result, another `.reduce()` pass could be used:

```
function intersection ( A , B ) 
{
    var m = A.reduce(function(m, v) { m[v] = 1; return m; }, {});
    return B.reduce(function(rv, v) {
      if (!rv.m[v]) {
        rv.m[v] = 1;
        rv.l.push(v);
      }
      return rv;
    }, {m:{}, l:[]}).l;
}
```

Comment: and If the values are objects but reference equality is all right, you can use a Set()

Comment: @Touffy yes good point, in fact you could use a Set anyway.  I haven't fully acclimated to ES2015 yet :)

Comment: Note that in practice, if A.length or B.length is small, you might actually get better performance with an array lookup: http://jsperf.com/key-or-array-search/2 (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353417/javascript-object-vs-array-lookup-performance)

Comment: @nrabinowitz yes, somehow modern browsers do `.indexOf()` incredibly quickly.

Comment: Or they have more overhead than expected for object key lookup.

Comment: wrong result with `[1, 2]`, `[1, 1]`

Comment: @Microsmsm right because it doesn't eliminate duplicates. A pass through `.reduce()` after the `.filter()` would deal with that. Answer updated.