# How to 'properly' intersect two Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

## Is There a proper way to intersect two Arrays in Javascript?

I am trying to intersect two arrays the **right way** but I find some difficulties

**my input isn't sorted** as assumed here 
[Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

My Code :

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums1
 * @param {number[]} nums2
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var intersect = function(nums1, nums2) {
    var t, a = nums1,b = nums2;
    if (b.length > a.length) t = b, b = a, a = t;
    return a.filter(x => b.includes(x))
};
console.log(intersect([1, 2], [1, 1])); //[1] correct
console.log(intersect([1, 1], [1, 2])); //[1,1] wrong
console.log(intersect([1], [1, 1])); //[1,1] wrong
console.log(intersect([1, 1, 1], [1, 1])); //[1,1,1] wrong
```

And tried that Algorithm from that Answer :
[Finding the intersection of two arrays in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786654/finding-the-intersection-of-two-arrays-in-javascript)

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums1
 * @param {number[]} nums2
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var intersect = function(nums1, nums2) {
  var A=nums1,B=nums2;
  var m = A.reduce(function(m, v) { m[v] = 1; return m; }, {});
  return B.filter(function(v) { return m[v]; });
};
console.log(intersect([1, 2], [1, 1])); //[1,1] wrong
console.log(intersect([1, 1], [1, 2])); //[1] right
console.log(intersect([1], [1, 1])); //[1,1] wrong
console.log(intersect([1, 1, 1], [1, 1])); //[1,1] right
```

Also tried this :

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums1
 * @param {number[]} nums2
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var intersect = function(nums1, nums2) {
  return nums1.filter((n) => nums2.indexOf(n) !== -1);
};
console.log(intersect([1, 2], [1, 1])); //[1] right
console.log(intersect([1, 1], [1, 2])); //[1,1] wrong
console.log(intersect([1], [1, 1])); //[1] right
console.log(intersect([1, 1, 1], [1, 1])); //[1,1,1] wrong
```

Also:

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums1
 * @param {number[]} nums2
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var intersect = function(nums1, nums2) {
  var a = nums1,b=nums2;
  var ai=0, bi=0;
  var result = [];

  while( ai < a.length && bi < b.length )
  {
     if      (a[ai] < b[bi] ){ ai++; }
     else if (a[ai] > b[bi] ){ bi++; }
     else /* they're equal */
     {
       result.push(a[ai]);
       ai++;
       bi++;
     }
  }

  return result;
};
console.log(intersect([1, 2], [1, 1])); //[1] right
console.log(intersect([1, 1], [1, 2])); //[1] right
console.log(intersect([1], [1, 1])); //[1] right
console.log(intersect([1, 1, 1], [1, 1])); //[1] right
console.log(intersect([2,1],[1,1])); //[] wrong
```

Where am I mistaken ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of your question is. What kind of answer do you expect? Do you want people to "fix" each of these implementations?

Comment: I am trying to find the perfect algorithm which passing all test cases

Comment: What do you mean by "intersect"? Do you mean combine all values of two arrays into a single array or copy all unique values of both arrays into a new single array, or what?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript

Comment: copy all unique values of smallest array intresecting with the bigger array into a new single array

Comment: If you research for 10 mins , you will get plenty of stuffs

Comment: @sumit I tried all not working

Comment: You missed the comment in the answer that post the last example. 'asuming inputs are ordered'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Comment: @vals my question not duplicated !

Comment: Why should `intersect([1, 1, 1], [1, 1])` yield `[1,1]`?  If we're really removing  duplicates, shouldn't that return `[1]`?

Comment: @ScottSauyet should return `[1,1]`

Comment: Yes, I'm asking *why*.  Before you figure out *how* you need to explain exactly *what* you're doing.  And I don't think those test cases are enough.

Comment: ... And how does that match "copy all unique values of smallest array intresecting with the bigger array into a new single array"?

Comment: Lol where was my brain when I didn't soret them and use the last method ! :D !
`.sort((a,b)=>a-b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums1
 * @param {number[]} nums2
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var intersect = function(nums1, nums2) {
    var arr = [], ind;
    while (nums1.length) {
        ind = nums2.indexOf(nums1.shift());
        if (ind > -1) {
            arr.push(nums2.splice(ind, 1)[0]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
};
```

Comment: Perfect and so easy to understand !

Comment: you are mutilating `nums2`.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, if you don't want to remove nums2 you can create copy of it `copy2 = nums2.slice(0)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and decrement the count if found for filtering.

```js
var intersect = function(nums1, nums2) {
    var m = new Map();
    
    nums1.forEach(a => m.set(a, (m.get(a) || 0) + 1));
    return nums2.filter(a => m.get(a) && m.set(a, m.get(a) - 1));
};

console.log(intersect([1, 2], [1, 1]));    // [1]
console.log(intersect([1, 1], [1, 2]));    // [1]
console.log(intersect([1], [1, 1]));       // [1]
console.log(intersect([1, 1, 1], [1, 1])); // [1, 1]
```

Comment: The last one should return `[1, 1]` though. Both arrays contain *two* `1`s.

Comment: Can u explain a bit ?

Comment: basically it takes a count of every element and filter if the value is not `0`. then decrement the count. otherwise return false for `Array#filter`.

Comment: Your code is working "just" like charm any more breaking down it ?

Comment: +1 for the god-awful, and yet still awesome, continual mutation of your helper structure and for making two statements into a single `&&` expression where the second clause is only there for it mutational side-effects.  Somewhere John Backus is weeping.

Answer (score 1):

One more implementation, using your approach 1 but removing the duplicates using the ES 6 `Set`

```js
    /**
     * @param {number[]} nums1
     * @param {number[]} nums2
     * @return {number[]}
     */
    var intersect = function(nums1, nums2) {
         var result = nums1.filter(x => nums2.includes(x));
         return [...new Set(result)];
    };

    console.log(intersect([1, 2], [1, 1])); //[1] correct
    console.log(intersect([1, 1], [1, 2])); //[1] correct
    console.log(intersect([1], [1, 1])); //[1] correct
    console.log(intersect([1, 1, 1], [1, 1])); //[1] correct
    console.log(intersect([1, 45, 143, 76, 11], [761,76, 11, 1])); //[1,76,11] correct
```

Comment: `[1, 1, 1], [1, 1]` should return `[1,1]`

Comment: what is your logic for intersection ?

Comment: Each element in the result should appear as many times as it shows in both arrays.

Comment: That's very different from what was said above.